# Terraform: How to use list or map to provision multiple storage containers in azurerm?

Tags: list, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I'm trying to create multiple storage containers to store remote state for multiple component groups in Terraform.

I have infrastructure, frontend, backend, and bastion vm's in my environment, each with its own .tf template so that I can deploy them individually as functional units of infrastructure.

I may need to add more types later, which suggests I need to store a list of components/environments as a variable and then just chunk through it to create the backend storage containers.

The major assumption here is that I can use the same storage account, but that I need separate containers for each remote state, otherwise they get commingled.

1. Is that assessment true?
2. How do I accomplish it syntactically using a list or some other device that minimizes code duplication?

Admittedly I am a Terraform beginner, so I expect I'm not grasping some basic rudiment of HCL. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
variable "component" {
  type    = list
  default = ["bastion", "frontproxy", "db", "infra"]
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 2.8"
  features {}
    }

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = "${lower(var.naming_prefix)}${random_integer.sa_num.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.setup.name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "ct" {
  #count                = length(var.component)
  name                 = "terraform-state${var.component}"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name

}
```

I've tried various notations including "count" (commented out in the example above) and referencing elements in azurerm_storage_container.ct.name, etc. and haven't gotten any traction.  What am I missing here?

Comment: as an aside, is it most helpful to a) only post the directly relevant code portions so there's less junk to wade through, or b) post a complete set of code that provisions all the prerequisites so that a reader can copy, paste, and reproduce the error?

Comment: Generally, you need to put the error message and the relevant code portions so that communities can help you solve the problem. The error message is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the assessment, I think it's not exactly correct. If you just need only one state file for each sperate component. I think only one container is enough. You can create one state file for each sperate component with different names so that you directly find the special file with the special name.  If you want to retain all the state files and set different names for each deployment of one component, then the assessment is right, you need to multiple containers for echo sperate component.

And then comes to the Terraform code, most codes are right, so you just need to change the code for the container like this:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "ct" {
  count                = length(var.component)
  name                 = "terraform-state-${element(var.component, count.index)}"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Charles Xu!  I found another way to increment through the elements in the list, but it works pretty much the same way the syntax you shared does:
`count                = length(var.component)
  name                 = "terraform-state-${var.component[count.index]}"`
Based on your suggestions, I will change the state name rather than the container name, now that I understand the difference.  I have marked your reply as the answer because it ultimately solved both my problems/questions.